# Show password in user credentials email in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to send the recently created user and email containing their credentials (username + password), but the password is hashed. How can I send plain passwords?

```
class AccountCreated extends Notification
{
   ...
   ...
    
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        self::$msg = $notifiable->password;
        return ['mail'];
    }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Don't send plain text passwords via email. This is a security problem. The user should now which password was entered, an in case of doubt the password reset function should be used.

Comment: this is for a read-only app and users are not experienced, they expect to receive their credentials by email. not really sure how to solve this. i'm using laravel nova btw.

Comment: If this is only a dummy internal app, then in the `create` function of your `RegisterController` you could send an email from there as you will have access to the `plaintext` password at that point.

Comment: i'm using an observer to send email notifications, can i get `plaintext` password on the observer class?

Answer (score 2):

You can't get plain passwords from Hashed password.
Find another away.
May be store it somewhere or use an encryption algorithm which
you can decrypt.